# Unity - shadows not showing up on iPhone?

Tags: c#, iphone, unity-game-engine, shadow

Alright, Im pretty new to unity and have asked on there but I cant figure out why this is happening - my realtime shadows show up perfectly in the Untiy editor but not on iPhone when actually deployed.

I look at http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/415449/mystery-no-iphone-shadows-example-project.html , however I checked my quality setting and they seem to be right (I need only hard shadows):

[image]

My light settings seem to be right as well, and I cant have it baked (has to be realtime) due to the look of my project. Here are my directional lights settings:

[image]

I have no idea whats happening here. I read that it might have to do with the model setting of the ground - my ground is made up of these .dae tiles, so I modified the normals to be calculated on my ground tile:

[image]

Mind you I didn't do this to all my other models, but Im not sure how that would affect anything. What am I doing wrong here? How can I make my realtime shadows show up on the iPhone?

Comment: Look at your quality Settings. They are set to "Simple" in the mobile column

Comment: That was it.. thank you. But my shadows are a lot softer on device than the editor- why is that?

Comment: They have blurry edges but are supposed to be hard